# force GNU-make to use modification time of symbolic link target, not modification time of the source

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu-make, symlink

I am experiencing a problem with modification times in GNU make 3.81.

My Makefile uses data mounted from a remote server which, for some reason unknown to me, has set the Modification Time of the files set into the far future (into the next century).

The Makefile first creates a symbolic link to the remote file "from the future" in a local directory and then based on this file runs several scripts which all generate some output files.

Now, when I want to rerun "make all" after it was interruped, to get all my output files, it will not restart with the latest output file it had generated (let's say from script number 3), but instead, it regenerates everything from start, since it notices that the first file (the one where I symlinked the file "from the future") is newer.

Is there an option to tell make to take the modification time of the symlink itself, and not the modification time of the symlink's target?

**Example**

Here is a minimal working example that regenerates the problem:

Set up folder and files:

```
mkdir symlinkmake
cd symlinkmake
echo $PWD > futurefile.txt
# set file modification time to the future
touch -t 212111111111 futurefile.txt
```

Content of the Makefile:

```
all: symlink.txt first_output.txt second_output.txt

symlink.txt:
    ln -s futurefile.txt symlink.txt

first_output.txt: symlink.txt
    cut -f1 -d"/" symlink.txt > first_output.txt

second_output.txt: first_output.txt
    wc first_output.txt > second_output.txt
```

Now run `make all` and delete the second output file. Then rerun make. Since the first output file already exists, only the second file needs to be generated. But as `futurefile.txt` is newer than any other file, the first output file will also be generated:

```
make all
rm second_output.txt
make all
```

On my machine the output looks like this:

```
$ ls
Makefile        futurefile.txt  symlink.txt
$ make all
make: Warning: File `symlink.txt' has modification time 3.3e+09 s in the future
cut -f1 -d"/" symlink.txt > first_output.txt
wc first_output.txt > second_output.txt
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
$ rm second_output.txt
$ make all
make: Warning: File `symlink.txt' has modification time 3.3e+09 s in the future
cut -f1 -d"/" symlink.txt > first_output.txt
wc first_output.txt > second_output.txt
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

Comment: There is the `--check-symlink-times` make option but it considers both modification times (the link and what it references) and takes... the most recent of the two. Not what you want. You should probably try to fix your date/time problem before staring an endless war with make.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Renaud Pacalet. I would really love to be able to fix the time problem on the remote machine, but this is, as far as I know, not possible without copying the data, which is what I want to avoid at all costs.

Comment: GNU make is open source.  It's probably not too difficult to adjust the code so that ONLY the symlink time is considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [`--check-symlink-times` make option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary) but:

> On systems that support symbolic links, this option causes make to consider the timestamps on any symbolic links in addition to the timestamp on the file referenced by those links. When this option is provided, the most recent timestamp among the file and the symbolic links is taken as the modification time for this target file.

This is not what you want which is to consider only the link's timestamp. As you cannot fix your date/time problem, I can imagine only one 2 solutions

1. [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) (OOP):

   ```
   .PHONY: all

   all: first_output.txt second_output.txt | symlink.txt

   symlink.txt:
       ln -s futurefile.txt $@

   first_output.txt: | symlink.txt
       cut -f1 -d"/" $| > $@

   second_output.txt: first_output.txt
       wc $< > $@
   ```

   `symlink.txt` being an OOP make will only consider its existence, not its timestamp. In other words, make will build it, and (re-)build all the targets that depend on it, only if it is missing.

   Note: I also used [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) everywhere it was possible. They are handy, less error prone and frequently allow to factorize rules.

   **Drawback**: this is more a quick and dirty hack than a real solution. Indeed, if the file referenced by the link changes, your other targets will **not** be rebuilt:

   ```
   $ ls -al
   Sep 14 14:55 Makefile
   Dec  1  2018 futurefile.txt
   $ make
   ln -s futurefile.txt symlink.txt
   cut -f1 -d"/" symlink.txt > first_output.txt
   wc first_output.txt > second_output.txt
   $ ls -al
   Sep 14 14:55 Makefile
   Sep 14 15:05 first_output.txt
   Dec  1  2018 futurefile.txt
   Sep 14 15:05 second_output.txt
   Sep 14 15:05 symlink.txt -> futurefile.txt
   $ make
   make: Warning: File 'symlink.txt' has modification time 6688452 s in the future
   make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
   make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
   $ touch --date=2018-12-02 futurefile.txt
   $ ls -al futurefile.txt
   $ make
   make: Warning: File 'symlink.txt' has modification time 6774852 s in the future
   make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
   make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
   ```
2. To mitigate the drawback of the first solution, you will have replace the date/time of your local host by the date/time of your remote server when building your targets. By chance, the `touch` command has a nice `--reference` option that force the timestamp of a file to be that of another file:

   ```
   .PHONY: all

   all: first_output.txt second_output.txt

   first_output.txt: futurefile.txt
       cut -f1 -d"/" $< > $@
       touch --reference=$< $@

   second_output.txt: first_output.txt
      wc $< > $@
      touch --reference=$< $@
   ```

   **Drawback**: instead of one symbolic link, you will have two files (`first_output.txt` and `second_output.txt`) with time in the future:

   ```
   $ ls -al
   Sep 14 14:55 Makefile
   Dec  1  2018 futurefile.txt
   $ make
   make: Warning: File 'futurefile.txt' has modification time 6688320 s in the future
   cut -f1 -d"/" futurefile.txt > first_output.txt
   touch --reference=futurefile.txt first_output.txt
   wc first_output.txt > second_output.txt
   touch --reference=first_output.txt second_output.txt
   make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
   $ ls -al
   Sep 14 14:55 Makefile
   Dec  1  2018 first_output.txt
   Dec  1  2018 futurefile.txt
   Dec  1  2018 second_output.txt
   $ make
   make: Warning: File 'first_output.txt' has modification time 6688320 s in the future
   make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
   make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
   $ touch --date=2018-12-02 futurefile.txt
   $ ls -al futurefile.txt
   $ make
   make: Warning: File 'first_output.txt' has modification time 6688320 s in the future
   cut -f1 -d"/" futurefile.txt > first_output.txt
   touch --reference=futurefile.txt first_output.txt
   wc first_output.txt > second_output.txt
   touch --reference=first_output.txt second_output.txt
   make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer! In my case option 1 is preferable, since I know that the files on the remote server will not be changed.